# read integer from file with read() c

Tags: c, file, integer, posix

i have a problem with file read() function. My file is like this:

```
4boat
5tiger
3end
```

Where the number is the length of the string that follows. I need to read integer and string from input file and print them out on stdoutput, using low level I/O. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int *len, fd, r_l, r_s;
    char *s;
    fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(fd>=0){
        do{
            r_l=read(fd, len, sizeof(int));
            r_s=read(fd, s, (*len)*sizeof(char));
            if(r_l>=0){
                write(1, len, sizeof(int));
                write(1, " ",sizeof(char));
            }
            if(r_s>=0)
                write(1, s, (*len)*sizeof(char));
        }while(r_l>=0 && r_s>=0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it not works =/

Comment: One problem is that the leading number is not, actually a number, it's a *character* which is one bytes (and `sizeof(int)` is typically 4 bytes).

Comment: Would there be strings longer then 9?

Comment: How about allocating storage for len (which you use for buffer in read()) and for s (which is also used as buffer in read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not allocate space for the poitner `len`, you need to allocate space for it and you can simply do it by declaring it as `int len;` so it gets allocated in the stack and you don't need to handle it's allocation manually, so it would be something like this

```
int main(void) {
    int len, fd, r_l, r_s;
    char *s;
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd >= 0) {
        do {
            r_l = read(fd, &len, sizeof(int));
            s   = malloc(len); /* <--- allocate space for `s' */
            r_s = 0;
            if (s != NULL)
                r_s = read(fd, s, len);
            if (r_l >= 0) {
                write(1, &len, sizeof(int));
                write(1, " ", 1);
            }
            if ((r_s >= 0) && (s != NULL))
                write(1, s, len);
            free(s);
        } while (r_l >= 0 && r_s >= 0);
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you also didn't allocate space for `s` which is another problem, I did allocate space for `s` in the corrected code above by using `malloc()`.

And `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, so you don't need that.

Although, the code above will not have the errors your code has, which invoke undefined behavior, it will not do what you expect, because your data cannot be read with this algorithm.

The numbers in your file are not really integers, they are characters, so what you really need is this

```
int main(void) {
    char chr;
    int len, fd, r_l, r_s;
    char *s;
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd >= 0) {
        do {
            r_l = read(fd, &chr, 1);
            len = chr - '0';
            s   = malloc(len); /* <--- allocate space for `s' */
            r_s = 0;
            if (s != NULL)
                r_s = read(fd, s, len);
            if (r_l >= 0) {
                printf("%d ", len);
            }
            if ((r_s >= 0) && (s != NULL))
                write(1, s, len);
            free(s);
        } while (r_l >= 0 && r_s >= 0);
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *must* check that malloc us successful.  Even simply writing `s = xmalloc(len)` and omitting a definition of `xmalloc` will suffice.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am checking that malloc is succesful, can't you see it? And all the headers are included in the OP's program. And where did you bring `xmalloc()` from? My program will not behave badly if `malloc()` fails, I am certain of that.

Comment: Also reading 1 byte into where `&len` points might fail depending on the system's endianess. Go and use a `char`.

Comment: @alk right again `len` was `int` and the code was leaving the rest of it uninitialized any way.

Comment: @alk yes it will not print the value, didn't think of that either.

Comment: You aren't on the run, are you? ;-)

Comment: You should share the `-1` you helped me a lot, do you want `-0.5`? ;-)

Comment: @iharob No, I didn't notice your checks that s is not NULL...you are doing it *very* non-idiomatically.  For a program like this, the typical behavior is to abort immediately, and xmalloc is a common name for a wrapper function that does just that. (Also, commonly "Malloc")